# Display only subcategories of a category and not sub-subcategories

Tags: categories, hierarchical

I have next code and i cant get it to list only the subcategories of a category and not sub-subcategories of the category.

I think the problem is the next line

```
    'hierarchical' => 0,
```

Do you know what can be the problem or what should i add in the next code to fix for what i want.

I've set it to 1 to 0, and nothing changes. This is a custom theme for a directory.

```
<?php // Get variables

global $def_cat_style;

$get_id_parent_cat = get_term_by( 'slug', $company_category, 'company_category' );

$args = array(

    'child_of' => $get_id_parent_cat->term_id ,

    'parent' => get_query_var(''),

    'orderby' => 'name',

    'order' => 'ASC',

    'hide_empty' => 0,

    'hierarchical' => 0,

    'taxonomy' => 'company_category',

    'pad_counts' => true );

$categories = get_categories($args);

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you need to provide the other PHP code, and you need to tell the name of the project that contains that code. Did you try to set the `'hierarchical'` to 3?

Comment: My full code is this: http://pastebin.com/fh5VUVFt , the problem is that i need to get 'depth' => 1, (only top level subcategories of the category you're on). And from what i reserch its not supported by get_categories it's supported by wp_list_categories, but it outputs it as a simple list, and i need that custom build i have because has css style and some options also build in theme. Maybe is a work around to do this with get_categories. Or if somebody know how can i output exactly like the one with get_categories using instead wp_list_categories. Regards.

Comment: I tryed something myself, but i think it has some problems with the echo, if, else.. http://pastebin.com/XXN0bv0L could help me, would it work?

Comment: I guess you need `'depth' => 2`.

Comment: depth is not supported for get_categories, only wp_list_categories.

Comment: Then try to implement your script with `wp_list_categories` if possible.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use your script and how it works? I'm willing to test it on my local server.

Comment: I got it working by using as parent the same value as child_of, thank you for your time. I used this: 'parent' => $get_id_parent_cat->term_id,

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($categories as $category){
    if ($category->parent != $get_id_parent_cat->term_id){
        //Do stuff with the category
    }
}
```

Comment: My full code is this: http://pastebin.com/fh5VUVFt if i add what you said it's the same, i think i have to do something else. Thanks for your help.